# How to play music from iTunes library located in a Windows 7 partition?

Tags: 10.04, windows, itunes

I have 2 partitions, one for Windows 7 and the other for Ubuntu 11.04.

All my music and the iTunes library is saved in the windows partition, but I'd like to be able to play these songs and use these playlists in ubuntu, but I don't want to copy all the songs and playlists from the windows partition.

Is it possible to play them directly from the windows partition and be able to use my playlists from my iTunes library? (I don't really care about which music player I'll need to use, feel free to give suggestions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to Windows partition you can play your files with any player.

For example you can use default player Banshee:

1. Open Banshee and press `Ctrl+I` (Import Media)
2. From the "Import From" drop-down menu select "iTunes Media Player" then locate your "iTunes Music Library.xml" file
3. Import

Comment: Out of curiosity, will the music in Banshee be updated automatically when the iTunes Music Library.xml file is?